# Showing uncaught type error in CreateJS. Not showing any output..my code is given below

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

its showing some error in createjs file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2014.12.12.min.js">
</script>       <script>
var preload,cW,cH,winW,winH;
var road,city1,city2,sky,build1,build2;
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("demoCanvas");
   var stage = new  createjs.Stage(canvas);
cW=1200;
cH=600;
    preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);

    var manifest =[{id:"ad_road",src:"road.png"},
        {id:"ad_build1",src:"build.png"},
        {id:"ad_build2",src:"build.png"},
        {id:"ad_farbuild1",src:"layer3.png"},
        {id:"ad_land",src:"land1.png"},
        {id:"ad_farbuild2",src:"layer1.jpg"},
        {id:"ad_sky",src:"sky.png"}
    ];
    preload.loadManifest(manifest);
    preload.on("complete",handleComplete);


function handleComplete(){
    sky = new createjs.Shape();
    sky.graphics.beginBitmapFill(preload.getResult("ad_sky"),"repeat-x").drawRect(0, 0, 1200,600);

    var roadImg = preload.getResult("road");
    road = new createjs.Shape();
    road.graphics.beginBitmapFill(roadImg).drawRect(0, 0, cW + roadImg.width, roadImg.height*1);
    road.tileW = roadImg.width;
    road.y = cH - roadImg.height;

    /*var matrix = new createjs.Matrix2D(1,2,3,4,5,6);*/

    build1 = new createjs.Bitmap(preload.getResult("ad_build1"));
    build1.setTransform(Math.random()*cW ,cH - build1.image.height * 0.7 - roadImg.height, 0.7,0.7);
    build1.alpha = 1;

    build2 = new createjs.Bitmap(preload.getResult("ad_build2"));
    //console.log(cH - build2.image.height * 1 - roadImg.height);
    build2.setTransform(Math.random()*cW ,cH - build2.image.height * 0.7 - roadImg.height, 0.7,0.7);
    build2.alpha = 1;

    stage.addChild(sky,build1,build2,road);
    createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
    document.onkeydown = tick;
}
    //createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);


function tick(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 37){
        var deltaS = event.delta / 1000 || 40/1000;
        road.x = (road.x - deltaS * 200) % road.tileW;

        build1.x = (build1.x - deltaS * 60);
        if (build1.x + build1.image.width * build1.scaleX <= 0) {
            build1.x = cW;
        }
        build2.x = (build2.x - deltaS * 75);
        if (build2.x + build2.image.width * build2.scaleX <= 0) {
            build2.x = cW;
        }
        stage.update(event);
    }
    }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><canvas height="600" id="demoCanvas" width="1300"> </canvas></p>
</body>
</html>
```

its showing the following error
console-log:Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: Is it possible one of your images is not loading? I dumped your code into a fiddle using a single loaded image, and it works. The "build2" doesn't display, likely due to the transform. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/fe6xkf81/

Comment: Yes, it looks like that error happens when the image you pass to the bitmapFill is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lanny stated in the comments, this error occurs when you pass an invalid image (empty, not fully loaded, corrupt, 404, etc) into `beginBitmapFill`.

Confirm that your image is loading properly.

I just pushed an update to EaselJS NEXT that bypasses this RTE, and ignores invalid bitmap fills.